# salesforce custom field value getting successfully updated through api but the updated field value not reflecting on sfdc ui page

Tags: custom-field, field-update

I have a custom field for an object for a sandbox account at the portal. When I am updating its value through sfdc api it gets updated successfully and is also reflecting the updated value in the object via api. However, the same field value is not reflecting the update when checked at the sf ui page. The security level for the account is of system admin profile and the field has editable permission. I have been searching a lot but not getting exact reason for the behaviour.

Comment: Usually, if the field is getting updated in the backend it will always appear on the standard layout. Couple of gotchas. 1. Make sure that the correct field is on the UI. Often we have two fields with same label. 2. Make sure you are updating the correct field on correct object. 3. Query the field via Developer console. Please let us know the results.

Comment: Also remember that you won't see the update in the UI without refreshing the page in most cases.

Comment: no in my custom field setting following are the settings:  Field Label -  RFQ Number ,   Field Name- RFQ_number and API Name- RFQ_number__c. The api field name ie. RFQ_number__c reflects in api and shows updated value as expected but corresponding Field Name value shows empty at UI